# multiple slideshow on one page using repeater fields

Tags: javascript, php, slideshow, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to display multiple slideshow on one page from my website.
I'm using a repeater ACF to enter my images.
I'm not able to know in advance how many slideshows are going to be displayed

when one slideshow is displayed, everything works perfectly, but when 2 are displayed, It doesn't work anymore.

does anyone knows how I can fix it ?

here is a basic code without the repeater and with 2 slideshows :

http://jsfiddle.net/XRpeA/13/

```
<div id="slideframe">
    <img class="image_news" src="http://s1.lemde.fr/image/2007/07/09/534x0/933544_5_aa6d_polynesie-bora-bora_0608bcead896ce3f59fc0e2fb3cc7435.jpg" />
    <img class="image_news" src="http://production.slashmedias.com/main_images/images/000/005/357/IMAGE-PENSEE-HD-1_original_original_large.jpg?1372235419" />
    <img class="image_news" src="http://images.telerama.fr/medias/2013/03/media_94814/une-image-un-film-l-auberge-de-dracula-1931,M106823.jpg" />
</div>
<br>
    <div id="counter">image <span id="current">1</span> / <span id="total"></span></div>

 <br><br>

<div id="slideframe">
<img class="image_news" src="http://s1.lemde.fr/image/2007/07/09/534x0/933544_5_aa6d_polynesie-bora-bora_0608bcead896ce3f59fc0e2fb3cc7435.jpg" />
<img class="image_news" src="http://production.slashmedias.com/main_images/images/000/005/357/IMAGE-PENSEE-HD-1_original_original_large.jpg?1372235419" />
<img class="image_news" src="http://images.telerama.fr/medias/2013/03/media_94814/une-image-un-film-l-auberge-de-dracula-1931,M106823.jpg" />
</div>
<br>
<div id="counter">image <span id="current">1</span> / <span id="total"></span></div>
```

and here is my code with the repeater :

http://jsfiddle.net/XRpeA/14/

```
<?php if(get_field('images')): ?>

<div id="counter_2"><span id="current">1</span> / <span id="total"></span></div>
    <div id="slideframe">

    <?php while(has_sub_field('images')): ?>
        <?php if(get_sub_field('image') != ''){ ?>
<img class="image_news" src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>"/>

<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?> 
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Are you testing this within jsfiddle, cause it doesn't run php... so that second jsfiddle is kind of no help.

Comment: I've tested the first one.
the second one is for my website

Answer (score 0):

**Ok, so I did it just for you as I promiced, thought I thought it will be faster :)**

**Result**

http://skyloveagency.com/new/
**(will remove tomorrow)**

**Fields:**

photo_repeater - **repeater**

---photo_slider - **repeater**

------photo_block - **image** with URL output

**Full script, not optimized but works perfectly**

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Profiles2 
*/

get_header(); ?>

<?php

// query

$args = array(

'post_type'          => 'profiles',

'show'               => 1

);

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

?>



<?php $random = 0;  
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php if(get_field('photo_repeater')): ?>

<?php while(has_sub_field('photo_repeater')): ?>

<?php $random++;  ?>        
<div id="slideframe<?php echo $random; ?>">

    <?php if(get_sub_field('photo_slider')): ?>

         <?php while( has_sub_field('photo_slider') ): ?> 

            <?php 
        $img_url = get_sub_field('photo_block');
        $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 200, 200, true );
        ?>
        <img class="image_news" src="<?php echo $image; ?>"  alt="111" />
         <?php endwhile; ?>     

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
<br>
<div id="counter<?php echo $random; ?>">image <span id="current<?php echo $random; ?>">1</span> / <span id="total<?php echo $random; ?>"></span></div>

<script>
var count<?php echo $random; ?> = $('#slideframe<?php echo $random; ?> .image_news').length;
$("#total<?php echo $random; ?>").text(count<?php echo $random; ?>);
// set display:none for all members of ".pic" class except the first
$('#slideframe<?php echo $random; ?> .image_news:gt(0)').hide();

// stores all matches for class="pic"
var $slides<?php echo $random; ?> = $('#slideframe<?php echo $random; ?> .image_news');

$slides<?php echo $random; ?>.click(function () {
// stores the currently-visible slide
var $current<?php echo $random; ?> = $(this);
if ($current<?php echo $random; ?>.is($slides<?php echo $random; ?>.last())) {
     $("#current<?php echo $random; ?>").text("1");
     $current<?php echo $random; ?>.hide();
     $slides<?php echo $random; ?>.first().show();
 }
// else, hide current slide and show the next one
else {
$("#current<?php echo $random; ?>").text($current<?php echo $random; ?>.next().index()+1);
$current<?php echo $random; ?>.hide().next().show();
    }
});
</script>
<br><br>    

<?php endwhile; ?> 


<?php endif; ?>     

<?php endwhile;  ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: thanks @AlexP, I understand what you mean in your first solution, that's what I'm trying to do...
can you help me with the first solution ? How can I ad an unique ID to both counter and slideframe ?

Comment: thanks for your help @AlexP
I'll try... can you please tell me more for the JS part ?

Comment: it is almost or even same as for PHP - just text it. Use js variable and assign it each time image row is triggered

Comment: well I have trouble to change my JS... I'm not using counter or slideframe in my JS... can you please take a look ? http://jsfiddle.net/f2Hu9/

Comment: thanks @AlexP, but it's not working. my photos are displayed, but all together, no slideshow... and the counter is just 1 / (blank)...
can't figure out what's the problem

Comment: I will do it in wordpress now, hold on 15 min

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41208/discussion-between-user2882154-and-alexp)

Comment: did you get my reply ?

Comment: Attaching solution instead of my last reply

Comment: Sorry, just forget it :)

Comment: thanks @AlexP, but it doesn't work for me.
I don't understand why you have 2 repeater fields.
I only have 1 repeater field named "images", and then my images fields  named "image_slider"... my Js is in my function.js file, Do I have to add it into my php file ? Can you check this jsfiddle and look if it's possible to combine your code with mine ?
http://jsfiddle.net/4cm6M/
thanks again for your help !